# Open up all the fields when I click add button in Ui-Grid Angular js

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Want to Open up all the fields when I click add button in Ui-Grid Angular js, But now its open up the field that has focus

http://plnkr.co/edit/CNYB4YuDpi2rTTw7r44N?p=preview `Here is my code in [plnkr]`

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9eOj.png)

Pls Advice

Answer (score 0):

Bud,

you need separate **row template** with `ng-if`:

- you create own property `row.$isEditing` for each row item
- you create button that toggles `row.$isEditing` for exact row
- after you done changes you hit *Save* button
- result will be placed in collection using `row.$index` of that row

  [Magica of templata](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/wiki/Templating)